# Excel.Application.Visibile not working on Office 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I need help reguarding the following code written in Visual Basic 6.0.

```
Private Sub cmdExcel_Click()
Dim obj As Object

Set obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

On Error Resume Next
   MkDir "c:\temp"
On Error GoTo 0

MousePointer = vbHourglass

On Error GoTo err

objGrid.m.ExportToXLS "c:\temp\test.xls"

obj.Workbooks.Open "c:\temp\test.xls"
obj.Visible = True
obj.Interactive = True


On Error GoTo 0

err:
  MousePointer = vbNormal

End Sub
```

**The enviroment**: Windows 10, Office Excel 2016.

**The problem**: the workbook doesn't show up, but I can still find an Excel instance in Task Manager. If I shut down the instance I can find the Excel in `c:\temp` and the application starts working again.

**The goal**: show the Excel just created.

Do you have any solutions?

Thanks in advance.
Sara

Comment: Try early binding by adding reference to excel object

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, but I found the solution and the problem wasn't in the code. I add it as an answer to my own post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. 
The problem wasn't in the code but in some Excel's settings.

First, I modified the code in order to get a more detailed error. Basically I switched the two instructions which allow Excel App to be visibile and the file to be opened:

```
obj.Visible = True
obj.Workbooks.Open "c:\temp\test.xls"
```

In this way, I was able to open Excel App and read the reason why the file could not be opened.

[image]

As you can see the file type is `Excel 4 Worksheets` which is blocked on opening.

I had to go `Trust Center` and disable it.
Just to be sure, I disabled also `Excel 4 Workbook`.

[image]

After performing the steps above, my app worked.